# UISegmentedControl Set Selected Index Without Animation

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITabBarController` with 3 views.  Each view has a `UISegmentedControl` in its navigation bar, and all of these segmented controls need to remain in sync.  Each time the `selectedSegmentIndex` on one of them changes, I fire an event that causes the others to change their `selectedSegmentIndex` as well.  I also set the index in `viewDidLoad` to ensure it is correct the first time the view is displayed.

This all works as expected, except that when I switch to a different view I can see the segmented control animate its button to the correct position, even though the `selectedSegmentIndex` may have been set much earlier.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?  Is there a way to disable this animation (when setting the index programmatically)?

Comment: Try wrapping the set in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622484-performwithoutanimation

Comment: Thank you for the response. Using performWithoutAnimation didn't have any effect.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: Not yet.  As far as I can tell the control waits until it is visible before animating its state.  I haven't found a way to disable the animation or force it to draw when its parent isn't visible.

Comment: We ended up putting the segmented control in a popup with some other controls.  However, when the user changes the selected item in the segmented control, we update the icon of the button that is used to display the popup.  This icon change is also delayed until the tab is visible.

Comment: Try wrapping in UIView.performWithoutAnimation and make sure you ask the layoutIfNeeded() on the segmented control at the end of the block.

Comment: UIView.performWithoutAnimation does work if you include layoutIfNeeded()

Answer (score 3):

Here is the working solution from the comments:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        segmentedControl.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is very late but in case anyone else needs same solution;

Layer of subviews of SegmentedControl has their own animation. Which are;

1. SelectionScale
2. SelectionPosition
3. SelectionBounds

here is a sample code from my project, I wrote whole new class for my UISegmentedControl

```
let foregroundIndex = numberOfSegments
if subviews.indices.contains(foregroundIndex),
    let foregroundImageView = subviews[foregroundIndex] as? UIImageView { 
        foregroundImageView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```

this is going to remove all animations over the selected UISegment and there will be no transition, it'll just snap.